# Result on determinant of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Let $A$ and $B$ be two $2×2$ real matrix. Then which of the following is true:

1. $det(A+B)+det(A-B)=det(A)+det(B)$
2. $det(A+B)+det(A-B)=2\times det(A)-2\times det(B)$
3. $det(A+B)+det(A-B)=2\times det(A)+2\times det(B)$
4. $det(A+B)-det(A-B)=2\times det(A)+2\times det(B)$

My try: Take $A=I$ and $ B=-I$ then clearly option 1,2 and 4 are discarded. But I cannot prove option 3. So please help me. Thank you in advance

Comment: It would be more common to see $2 \det (A)$ than $2 \times det(A)$.

Answer (score 2):

By the multilinearity of the determinant function,
\begin{aligned}
&\det(u+x,v+y)+\det(u-x,v-y)\\
=&\big(\det(u,v)+\det(u,y)+\det(x,v)+\det(x,y)\big)
+\big(\det(u,v)-\det(u,y)-\det(x,v)+\det(x,y)\big)\\
=&2\det(u,v)+2\det(x,y).
\end{aligned}

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$
\det(A+B)+\det(A-B)=2a_1a_4 - 2a_2a_3 + 2b_1b_4 - 2b_2b_3=2\det(A)+2\det(B)
$$
by a direct computation. Here $A$ has the entries $a_i$ and $B$ the entries $b_i$.